# Eigenvector of matrix theory question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have a matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -2 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
The eigenvalues of this matrix are:

$$\lambda_{1,2}=1$$

$$\lambda_2=0$$

I have a few questions regarding understanding why we do some things:

1. To find the eigenvalues we have written $$det{(A-\lambda{I})}=...$$
   and we calculate from there.
   In many books, I 've seen that the notation is $$det{(\lambda{I}-A)}=...$$
   What is the difference between these two notations, to calculate eigenvalues?
2. I've seen that eigenvectors never have the solution: 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0\\
   0\\
   0
   \end{bmatrix} 
   Why is that so?

And also another question is why in verified solutions of eigenvectors there is always one zero in the vector column (I mean, I 've never seen an eigenvector to be represented as $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$), even if that was a solution of the $\ker{(A-\lambda{I})}$, with which we calculate eigenvectors.

If I understand kernel correctly, it represents all the vectors from one space that by a linear transformation, get transformed to zero vector in another vector space.
Why is the previous assumption that $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ is also one of those vectors wrong if it is a matrix solution when we do $\ker{(A-\lambda{I}}):\quad...$

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix of size $n$, then $\det (A-tI) = (-1)^n \text{det}(tI-A)$. Can you see why it holds?

Comment: @AshishK Is it because of the signature? When we have $(-1)^{n+m}$, where it depends on the location of the element in the matrix if $n+m$ is even or odd?

Comment: As Ashish K pointed out, it doesn't matter which definition if the characteristic polynomial you use, each is going to give you the same eigenvalues. An eigenvector does not necessarily have a 0 coordinate, there are matrices whose eigenvectors have all nonzero coordinates. The zero vector is never an eigenvector by definition. The idea behind this is the Jordan decomposition of a matrix, i.e. to change your basis to a basis consisting of eigenvectors of the matrix. The 0 vector is never a proper basisvector.

Comment: The reason we forbid counting the zero vector as an eigenvector is that for all matrices $A$ and all numbers $\lambda$, $A0=\lambda0$, that is, every number would be an eigenvalue for every matrix, which would be stupid.

Comment: Your remaining question appears to be based on a misunderstanding.  Eigenvectors are *not* required to have at least one zero entry. The eigenvectors of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{-1&1&-1\\7&2&-10\\1&1&-3}\ ,
$$
for instance, are
$$
\pmatrix{1\\1\\1},\ \pmatrix{1\\3\\1}\ \text{and }\ \pmatrix{2\\-1\\1}\ ,
$$
corresponding to eigenvalues $-1, 1$ and $-2$, respectively.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera It was, I see. Thank you for explaining